# Custom marker not rerendering after coordinates change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

I'm trying to move some markers around the map but after update the array which contains the info about the coordinates of them nothing happens, it's just blinking but not moving.

**BusMarker.js (Customer Marker)**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Marker } from 'react-native-maps'

const BusMarker = props => {
  const { longitude, latitude, plate } = props

  const [coordinates] = useState({
    longitude: Number(longitude),
    latitude: Number(latitude)
  })

  return (
    <Marker
      key={`bus-${plate}-${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`}
      coordinate={coordinates}
      image={require('../../img/icon/bus-icon.png')}>
    </Marker>
  )
}

export default BusMarker
```

**Map.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment, useCallback, useRef } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps'
import BusMarker from './BusMarker'
import { useFocusEffect } from 'react-navigation-hooks'

const Maps = () => {
  const [busLocation, setBusLocation] = useState([
    {
      "plate": "CAR1203",
      "latitude": 0,
      "longitude": 0,
    },
  ])

  const [region] = useState({
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0143,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0134,
  })

  const _renderBusesOnMap = busLocation => {
    if (busLocation.length > 0) {
      return busLocation.map(({ plate, longitude, latitude }) => {
        return (
          <BusMarker key={plate} plate={plate} longitude={longitude} latitude={latitude} />
        )
      })
    }
  }

  const updateLocations = () => {
    const newPosition = [
      {
        "plate": "CAR1203",
        "latitude": 0,
        "longitude": 1,
      },
    ]

    const timeout = setInterval(() => {
      setBusLocation(newPosition)
    }, 1000)
  }

  useEffect(updateLocations, [])

  return (
    <MapView
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      style={styles.map}
      initialRegion={region}
      showsCompass={false}
      showsTraffic={false}
      showsIndoors={false}
      showsBuildings={false}
      showsPointsOfInterest={false}
      loadingEnabled={false}
    >
      {_renderBusesOnMap(busLocation)}
    </MapView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffff',
    height: '100%'
  },
})

export default Maps
```

Why is it not updating its location on the map?

I'm using the following versions on this project:
React Native: 0.60.5
React Native Maps: 0.25.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
const BusMarker = props => {
  const { longitude, latitude, plate } = props;

  const coordinates = {
    longitude: Number(longitude),
    latitude: Number(latitude)
  };

  return (
    <Marker
      key={`bus-${plate}-${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`}
      coordinate={coordinates}
    />
  );
};

const Maps = () => {
  const [busLocation, setBusLocation] = useState([
    {
      plate: "CAR1203",
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324
    }
  ]);

  const [region] = useState({
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421
  });

  const _renderBusesOnMap = busLocation => {
    if (busLocation.length > 0) {
      return busLocation.map(({ plate, longitude, latitude }) => {
        return (
          <BusMarker
            key={plate}
            plate={plate}
            longitude={longitude}
            latitude={latitude}
          />
        );
      });
    }
  };

  const updateLocations = () => {
    const newPosition = [
      {
        plate: "CAR1203",
        latitude: 37.78845,
        longitude: -122.4424
      }
    ];

    const timeout = setInterval(() => {
      setBusLocation(newPosition);
    }, 1000);
  };

  useEffect(updateLocations, []);

  return (
    <MapView
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      style={styles.map}
      initialRegion={region}
      showsCompass={false}
      showsTraffic={false}
      showsIndoors={false}
      showsBuildings={false}
      showsPointsOfInterest={false}
      loadingEnabled={false}
    >
      {_renderBusesOnMap(busLocation)}
    </MapView>
  );
};
```

The main problem I think is the way you set `coordinates` inside `BusMarker`. There is no need to use `useState` there. You can just set `coordinates` as an object with the latitude and longitude values you receive from props.

I've adjusted the coordinates to make it easier to test.

---

**Update**

I will try to add to this answer, by explaining my understanding of the behavior. I will explain by giving a more general example. So let's say you have code like this:

```
const Component = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(props);
// ...
```

Now `props` will be set as the initial value of `data`.

But useState won't update on props change this way. So even though the props have changed, `data` still holds the value it was initially passed.  To tell `data` to update on props change you could use `useEffect` inside `Component`:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setData(props);
}, [props]);
```

But like I said in my original answer, there is no reason to use `useState` in this situation. We don't need to keep `Component`'s state in sync with the parent `props` as we can simply use `props` directly. **So don't use the `useEffect` approach I've given as it's unnecessary, it's just to give an example**.

Comment: It works! THANK YOU SO MUCH! Could you explain me why it doenst rerender with useState?

Comment: I've updated my answer and tried to give an explanation of what I think is happening.